# Spring file upload in a mixed form

Tags: java, spring, file-upload, spring-mvc

I want to upload a file to my spring 3.0 applicatoin (created with roo).

I already have the following entity:

```
@Entity
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooEntity
public class SelniumFile {

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = ShowCase.class)
    @JoinColumn
    private ShowCase showcase;

    @Lob
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private byte[] file;

    @NotNull
    private String name;
}
```

But I am not sure how to implement it on the view/controller side. Can I freely mix spring-form tags like `<form:input>` with normal tags like `<input type=file ...>`?

I have seen the nice [multipart upload section](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart) in the MVC-Documentation but still need a little help to apply it to my specific case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update: I think my question was badly formulated. What I wanted to do is create a spring

I found a very good explanation on how to do it in the older spring documentation and applied it to the new Spring 3.0 MVC. Basically this means you need to register a PropertyEditor in your controllers  @InitBinder method. Afterwards everything will behave as expected (provided you have added MultiPartResolver to the context and set the correct form encoding).
Here is my sample:

```
@RequestMapping("/scriptfile/**")
@Controller
public class ScriptFileController {

    //we need a special property-editor that knows how to bind the data
    //from the request to a byte[]
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder)
    {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(byte[].class, new ByteArrayMultipartFileEditor());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/scriptfile", method = RequestMethod.POST)    
    public String create(@Valid ScriptFile scriptFile, BindingResult result, ModelMap modelMap) {    
        if (scriptFile == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("A scriptFile is required");        
        if (result.hasErrors()) {        
            modelMap.addAttribute("scriptFile", scriptFile);            
            modelMap.addAttribute("showcases", ShowCase.findAllShowCases());            
            return "scriptfile/create";            
        }        
        scriptFile.persist();        
        return "redirect:/scriptfile/" + scriptFile.getId();        
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe you can mix-and-match file uploads with normal forms (in Spring MVC, at least), because file upload forms use the `multipart/form-data` encoding, rather than the usual `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

When you specify `multipart/form-data`, then in Spring you need to use a  `MultipartResolver` implementation (as mentioned in the Spring docs you linked to), and all parameter decoding must go through that. Spring MVC will not be able to decode the normal form inputs, since all fields will be encoded along with the uploaded file.

It's almost certainly easier to use two separate forms, one for the normal stuff, one for the file upload.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll try that and report back if it worked.

Comment: How would I do this with my existing entity?
I've managed to get the example from the mvc-docs working for me. 
But the problematic part is: now that I have the byte[] in my controller method, I need to do something with it ;-) 
E.g. I have a DataFile entity and now I want to bind the byte[] that was uploaded via my FileUploadController to such an entity and sotre that in the database. How would I do that?

Comment: hello @skaffman. I am now focusing on a Spring app and I realized that what you said doesn't hold in my case. I could instantiate an object whose fields are populated from form, both text and file. Has, in the meanwhile, anything changed in Spring? Thanks

Comment: Might this: https://www.viralpatel.net/tutorial-save-get-blob-object-spring-3-mvc-hibernate/  ever disprove your explanation?? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-442 for the related Roo issue.

Comment: Already voted on that one. And btw: Nice to see you round here, Ben ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring 3.0 then you can create a Converter and a Formatter(optional) And you won't have to use the initBinder method, and keep things more POJO, but your solution is still very valid and still quite clean.

Comment: I haven't looked into Converters/Formatters yet, but so far registering the CustomEditor seems quite easy to me. Note: I only had to register it. I didn't have the "joy" to write a custom property-editor ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two forms, one to upload file and other to upload data. I think about this because a file is big archive or a litle and because this situation this do not work in a easy way.