# How to create the file browser in view for spring roo?

Tags: spring, file-upload, spring-roo

I'm new in spring roo. I want to create a page with file upload.  I used spring roo to create all pages and i try to use it to create a file browser button in file upload page.  The problem is spring roo using spring form tag which doesn't have file browser.  I solve this problem by using html input type="file" tag instead, but the spring roo showed the error like this "Failed to invoke handler method [public void egat.spring.roo.ptu.io.web.ImportExcelController.post(java.lang.Long,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find @PathVariable [id] in @RequestMapping "

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is defect in jira raised against this issue you can vote for it.

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-442

Answer (score 0):

[Spring file upload in a mixed form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190851/spring-file-upload-in-a-mixed-form)

Check this out till this bug is resolved