# Cannot convert MultipartFile into Blob in Spring

Tags: spring, file, spring-mvc, blob, multipartform-data

I am trying to save an uploaded file as Blob in a MySql record. I am new to Spring. When I am about to save the record after uploading a file, then when my POST method `updateCandidate()` executes, I get this exception:

> Field error in object 'candidateForm' on field 'cv': rejected value [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile@59c09df6]; codes [typeMismatch.candidateForm.cv,typeMismatch.cv,typeMismatch.java.sql.Blob,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [candidateForm.cv,cv]; arguments []; default message [cv]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'java.sql.Blob' for property 'cv'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'java.sql.Blob' for property 'cv': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]

What is going wrong? How to fix?

My entity:

```
import java.sql.Blob;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;

@Entity
public class Candidate {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
@Column(unique = true)
private String ssn;
private String name;
private String surname;
private String technology;
private String media;
@Lob
private Blob cv;
private boolean activeCV;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getSsn() {
    return ssn;
}
public void setSsn(String ssn) {
    this.ssn = ssn;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}
public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}
public String getTechnology() {
    return technology;
}
public void setTechnology(String technology) {
    this.technology = technology;
}
public String getMedia() {
    return media;
}
public void setMedia(String media) {
    this.media = media;
}
public Blob getCv() {
    return cv;
}
public void setCv(Blob cv) {
    this.cv = cv;
}
public boolean isActiveCV() {
    return activeCV;
}
public void setActiveCV(boolean activeCV) {
    this.activeCV = activeCV;
}

}
```

In my service:

```
@Autowired
private CandidateRepository repository;

...

public Optional<Candidate> getCandidate(Long id){
    return repository.findById(id);
}

public void addOrUpdateCandidate(Candidate candidate) {
    repository.save(candidate);
}
```

In my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/candidates")
public class CandidateController {

@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory emf;

@Autowired
private CandidateService service;

...

@GetMapping("/updateCandidate/{id}")
public String showUpdateUserForm(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {
    Candidate candidate = service.getCandidate(id).get();
    model.addAttribute("candidateForm", candidate);
    return "updateCandidateForm";
}

@PostMapping("/updateCandidate/updateCandidateResult")
public String updateCandidate(@ModelAttribute("candidateForm") Candidate candidate, @RequestParam("cv") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    InputStream iStream = file.getInputStream();
    long size = file.getSize();
    Session session = emf.unwrap(Session.class);
    Blob cv = Hibernate.getLobCreator(session).createBlob(iStream, size);
    candidate.setCv(cv);
    service.addOrUpdateCandidate(candidate);
    return "updateCandidateResult";
}
}
```

My updateCandidateForm.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
    <body>

        <form:form method="POST" action="updateCandidateResult" modelAttribute="candidateForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <form:hidden path="id"/>
         <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="name"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="surname">Surname</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="surname"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="ssn">SSN</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="ssn"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="technology">Known Technology</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="technology"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="media">Found us on</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="media"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="cv">Select a cv</form:label></td>
                <td><input type="file" name="cv" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="activeCV">Active CV</form:label></td>
                <td><form:checkbox path="activeCV" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</body>
```

In my POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**EDIT 1** (question):
Would there be even a way of preventing Spring from trying to convert MultipartFile to Blob at "Submit-time", triggering this operation sooner, having the POST method already manage the Candidate (with Blob field already set) object?

**EDIT 2:**
as suggested by JB Nizet, I tried to use a support POJO, which has the field CV of the type MultipartFile, to store temporarily what I post via form (text fields + file field), and I don't get that exception anymore, because at "Submit-time" the populated object has the cv field of the type of the uploaded file:

```
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

public class CandidatePOJO {

private Long id;
private String ssn;
private String name;
private String surname;
private String technology;
private String media;
private MultipartFile cv;
private boolean activeCV;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "CandidatePOJO [id=" + id + ", ssn=" + ssn + ", name=" + name + ", surname=" + surname + ", technology="
            + technology + ", media=" + media + ", cv=" + cv + ", activeCV=" + activeCV + "]";
}
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getSsn() {
    return ssn;
}
public void setSsn(String ssn) {
    this.ssn = ssn;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}
public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}
public String getTechnology() {
    return technology;
}
public void setTechnology(String technology) {
    this.technology = technology;
}
public String getMedia() {
    return media;
}
public void setMedia(String media) {
    this.media = media;
}
public MultipartFile getCv() {
    return cv;
}
public void setCv(MultipartFile cv) {
    this.cv = cv;
}
public boolean isActiveCV() {
    return activeCV;
}
public void setActiveCV(boolean activeCV) {
    this.activeCV = activeCV;
}
}
```

in controller, now my first concern is to see whether the pojo can be correctly instantiated, so my GET-POST pair is:

```
@GetMapping("/updateCandidate/{id}")
public String showUpdateUserForm(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {
    CandidatePOJO candidatePOJO = new CandidatePOJO();
    candidatePOJO.setId(id);
    model.addAttribute("candidateForm", candidatePOJO);
    return "updateCandidateForm";
}

@PostMapping("/updateCandidate/updateCandidateResult")
public String updateCandidate(@ModelAttribute("candidateForm") CandidatePOJO candidatePOJO) {
    System.out.println("CANDIDATE POJO");
    System.out.println(candidatePOJO.toString());   // here I notice id = null

    /* MultipartFile to Blob conversion */
    //  MultipartFile file = candidatePOJO.getCv();
    //  InputStream iStream = file.getInputStream();
    //  long size = file.getSize();
    //  Session session = emf.unwrap(Session.class);
    //  Blob cv = Hibernate.getLobCreator(session).createBlob(iStream, size);

    /* instantiating the entity object to be freezed in db */
    // Candidate candidate = new Candidate();
    // set all data from candidatePOJO..
    //      candidate.setCv(cv);

    //  service.addOrUpdateCandidate(candidate);
    return "updateCandidateResult";
}
```

and I get a CandidatePOJO object with no id set. I don't manage to have the id pass from GET to POST. Does anyone know what is gong wrong?

**EDIT 3:**
after many days I opted for the solution with a support POJO, unbelievably I am noticing that the ID is passed from the GET method to the POST one (I haven't changed anything, I have just performed the classical Maven project cleaning as I did when I posted my issue). Unluckily I am facing now another exception (after restoring the code previously commented in the POST method, of course):

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Hibernate cannot unwrap EntityManagerFactory as 'org.hibernate.Session'

How to fix that?

**EDIT 4:**
Exception just above solved replacing:

```
Session session = emf.unwrap(Session.class);
```

with:

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
Session session = (Session) em.getDelegate();
```

Comment: The exception says it all: your method has a Candidate as argument, and Spring is thus supposed to populate its properties from the parameters of the request. But it can't populate the property of type Blob from the multipart file you're sending. Just don't use your persistent entity for your candidateForm. Use a dedicated class, which represents what the client is sending, and not what the database row contains.

Comment: I am constrained from using Blob as that field type. So, if I get it well, it tries the conversion as the POST starts executing and stops when it can't do that, so that it can't even get to elaborate my coded conversion (?). Could you please write some code? :)

Comment: Create a class. A simple POJO, with getters and setters for every parameter that is supposed to be sent by the form, and the appropriate types. Use that class, and not Candidate, as your command. Copy the data from this command object to your entity, applying the necessary transformations.

Comment: Hello @JBNizet, I used a POJO as you said. If I coded correctly, the system throws me the same exception, confirming my belief that it's not the type of the object (Entity bean, POJO) that makes confusion. If indeed I coded wrongly, I would like to figure out what's the right thing to do. I would like to show you how I edited my GET and POST. I don't know how to open the chat box here. Forgive me for my possible errors with english. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I was omitting something. Now it works partially. I can have the system instantiate the Candidate POJO (with cv type not Blob but MultipartFile), but it doesn't set the id, so my POST retrieves an object with a field not set

Comment: Your POJO must lack a setter for the ID.

Comment: No. It has that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204544/discussion-between-tom-and-jb-nizet).

Comment: the fact that I could populate my POJO object with both normal text fields and file, doesn't, and I would like to understand why, disprove this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2191075/6528351 ?? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BY USING SUPPORT POJO, I finally solved. Indeed I had already solved earlier, by code. The code in the post is right (**EDIT 2**). When I often performed Maven project cleaning, this didn't discover the errors. I performed it in the last hours and unbelievably my code worked. I can't guess the magic :D I don't know what really happened. By code, I solved in two different ways. First:

```
@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory emf;

// ........

@GetMapping("/updateCandidate/{id}")
public String showUpdateUserForm(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {
    Candidate candidate = service.getCandidate(id).get();

    CandidatePOJO candidatePOJO = new CandidatePOJO();
    candidatePOJO.setId(id);
    candidatePOJO.setName(candidate.getName());
    candidatePOJO.setSurname(candidate.getSurname());
    candidatePOJO.setSsn(candidate.getSsn());
    candidatePOJO.setMedia(candidate.getMedia());
    candidatePOJO.setTechnology(candidate.getTechnology());
    candidatePOJO.setActiveCV(candidate.isActiveCV());

    model.addAttribute("candidateForm", candidatePOJO);
    return "updateCandidateForm";
}

@PostMapping("/updateCandidate/updateCandidateResult")
public String updateCandidate(@ModelAttribute("candidateForm") CandidatePOJO candidatePOJO) throws IOException {
    MultipartFile file = candidatePOJO.getCv();
    InputStream iStream = file.getInputStream();
    long size = file.getSize();
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    Session session = (Session) em.getDelegate();
    Blob cv = Hibernate.getLobCreator(session).createBlob(iStream, size);

    Candidate candidate = new Candidate();
    candidate.setId(candidatePOJO.getId());
    candidate.setName(candidatePOJO.getName());
    candidate.setSurname(candidatePOJO.getSurname());
    candidate.setSsn(candidatePOJO.getSsn());
    candidate.setMedia(candidatePOJO.getMedia());
    candidate.setTechnology(candidatePOJO.getTechnology());
    candidate.setActiveCV(candidatePOJO.isActiveCV());
    candidate.setCv(cv);

    service.addOrUpdateCandidate(candidate);
    return "updateCandidateResult";
}
```

Second (with the same GET):

```
@PostMapping("/updateCandidate/updateCandidateResult")
public String updateCandidate(@ModelAttribute("candidateForm") CandidatePOJO candidatePOJO) throws IOException, SerialException, SQLException {
    MultipartFile file = candidatePOJO.getCv();
    Blob cv = new SerialBlob(file.getBytes());

    Candidate candidate = new Candidate();
    candidate.setId(candidatePOJO.getId());
    candidate.setName(candidatePOJO.getName());
    candidate.setSurname(candidatePOJO.getSurname());
    candidate.setSsn(candidatePOJO.getSsn());
    candidate.setMedia(candidatePOJO.getMedia());
    candidate.setTechnology(candidatePOJO.getTechnology());
    candidate.setActiveCV(candidatePOJO.isActiveCV());
    candidate.setCv(cv);

    service.addOrUpdateCandidate(candidate);
    return "updateCandidateResult";
}
```

Being new to Spring, I don't know the differences yet. I would appreciate a lot an explanation. Moreover, I want to modify, sooner or later, this code, in order to get rid of the support POJO and to work with just the entity objects: if anyone can solve my initial issue, I would be forever grateful!